# Cannot display double curly braces in react useTranslation()

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-i18next

```
import React from 'react';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

export function MyComponent() {
    const { t } = useTranslation()
    const param = "{{someString}}"
    return <p>{t('translate', {param})}</p>   
}
```

translation.json:
"translate": "my output string {{param}}"

wanted output: my output string {{someString}}

Comment: Does it help when you leave the curly braces around {param} and change it to `return <p>{t('translate', param)}</p>`?

Comment: the problem is when there is curly braces in the parameter it won't display anything at all

Answer (score 3):

It's actually a feature of i18next when it makes interpolation in nested values. Their docs is not clear enough in "Interpolation" section but `skipOnVariables` entry in the [very bottom of interpolation's options](https://www.i18next.com/translation-function/interpolation) is clear:

> Another example:
> `t('key', { a: '{{otherVar}}': otherVar: 'another value' })`
> this will not resolve the `otherVar` variable and will use `{{otherVar}}` as the variable value.

The easy but redundant way is to specify `skipOnVariables` right in the `t()` call:

```
  return <p>{t('translate', {
    param, 
    interpolation: { skipOnVariables: false } 
  })}</p>
```

But if you have a lot of instances, you may want to specify this on instance level for `i18n.init()`

Another hack is to inject zero-width space in between the braces(if your translation is 100% static):

```
const param = "{\u200b{someString}}"
return <p>{t('translate', {param})}</p>
```